# Unrecognised selector sent to instance when adding tracking area

Tags: objective-c, macos, unrecognized-selector, nstrackingarea

I have an NSImage in an NSPanel in which I'd like to get the mouse X, Y co-ords.

If I set the NSImage layer content with`layer.content =splitNSImage` (where splitNSImage is an NSImage created from a URL)and then

```
NSRect layerBounds = [layer bounds];
NSTrackingAreaOptions options = (NSTrackingActiveAlways|NStrackingInVisibleRect|NSTrackingMouseEnter|
NSTrackingMouseExit|NSTrackingMouseMoved);
NSTrackingArea *trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:layerBounds owner:self userinfo:nil];
[[layer contents] addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
```

I get a runtime error "Thread 1: "-[NSImage addTrackingArea:]: Unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x600003335400" on the last line.

If I use the use `[NSPanel contentView]`  instead of `[layer contents]` it works OK but gives the mouse co-ords (in the MouseMoved event) in the panel rather than the imageView

Comment: `NSImage` doesn't have a `addTrackingArea` method.  You'd need to add it to the `NSView` instead but then manage how the image is set within the view, which probably won't be trivial.

Comment: use NSImageView to add a tracking area `NSImageView *imgview = ...; imgview.image=yourimage; [imgview addTrackingArea:<#(nonnull NSTrackingArea *)#>];`

Comment: Nodoby even knows under which class you are writing code.